# For loop iterations for two objects in same loop

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am using models.py to submit one file with different attributes as month and year, when the user passes month and year, then it should match with the objects in database and return the file. I appended all the files in a dictionary and returned it to the HTML. But its not displaying the result

```
#views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Results


def allresults(request):
    results = Results.objects.all()
    mon = request.POST['mahina']
    yea = request.POST['saal']

    if (mon == 'all'):
        pdf_url = {}

        for i in results:
            m = i.month
            y = i.year
            f = i.file
            u = f.url
            if (yea == y):
                pdf_url[f] = u
    pl = pdf_url.items()
    return render(request, 'results/allresults.html', {'y': yea, 'pl': pl})
```

```
#models.py
from django.db import models


class Results(models.Model):
    date = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    month = models.CharField(max_length=22)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='file/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.date
```

```
{% for i,j in pl %}

            <strong>@  result.date </strong><span> result.title</span>
<span style="float: right;"><a href="{{ j }}"><img src="{% static 'pdf.jpg'%}"></a></span>
          </p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I can't see `{{i}}` in that template. I only visually grep'ed it, but would expect it to be after the `<a href=...>` and before `</a>`. (You really want to put more newlines in that template!)

Comment: i have put {{ j }} as that will contain the url which will be inside href of 'a'tag

Comment: Might be  a stupid comment, but have you checked that there are any `Results` objects in your DB? The code will work fine with no objects, will just output nothing.

Comment: at first when i tried to print all the files present in the DB, then i tried 'Results.objects', and used this as 'result'(variable) in the HTML with a for loop as:  for i in result.all . This worked fine then... Shall i share your the postgres DB screenshot?

Comment: It will also work fine but do nothing  if `yea` does not match any result.year for any Result object in the database. Check `request.POST['saal']`. You may need to add a type conversion. `"2019" == 2019`  is False.

Comment: How can I achieve that? How can I compare the objects in DB with a value?

Comment: Assuming you are using the development server, put a print statement in your code! Or use your preferred logging or debugging solution.

Comment: Are you using python 3 ? If so, try this : `pl = dict(pdf_url.items())`.

Comment: Thanks, the type casting worked...

Comment: @albar I have tried this already and its also working. But i have date, title and also the dictionary and i want them to be run in the same loop. And I am unable to do that...

Comment: I added both date and title in a variable and then passed it as key and the url and a value for a dictionary. Then looped through the dictionary.items() inside the template with respective key and value. This worked for me.